# create a new element as much as the value of the input

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I create element dynamically, and the amount of the element is based on the input text
Thanks before..

Comment: Do you wish to create an array of elements, with the number of elements in the array as large as some input value?

Comment: Read the value and create the elements in a loop. What have you tried so far?

Comment: right,
and the element is combo box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly I found it

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#amount").keyup(function() {
        var amount = $("#amount").val();
        var i;
        if(amount != ""){
            for(i=1;i<amount;i++){
               var c = $('#cloned:first').clone(true);
               c.attr("class","cloned");
               $('#cloned:last').after(c);
            }
            $('#tr_table').show("slow");
            $("#hidden").val($("#amount").val());
        }else if(amount == ""){
            var j = $("#hidden").val();
            for(var k=1;k<j;k++){
                $("#cloned").remove();
            }
            $("#tr_table").hide("slow");
        }

    })
})
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="amount">
        <input type="hidden" id="hidden">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr_table" style="display: none;">
    <td>
        <table id="cloned">
            <tr>
                <td>Some Label</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="SOME INPUT" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="txt">
<a id="elm">create elemrnt</a>

<div id="foo">
</div>





  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#elm").click(function(){

var a = parseInt($("#txt").val());

var i=0;
for (i=1;i<=a;i++)
{
     $("#foo").append("<div>hello world</div>");
    }

});

});
```